# Counting - based on output from two tables

Tags: sql, count, multiple-tables

I have two tables: master and class.  Master is a master list of all students that have ever attended the school with studentID and Social Security Number (SSN).  I'm worried that honors students have been assigned multiple student ID's.  I would like to count studentID's for each SSN.

```
select master.studentID, master.SSN, class.studentID, class.type
from master, class
where master.studentID = class.student.ID and class.type = 'Honors" and count(master.StudentID) > 1
```

I get the following error message:  "Use of function COUNT not valid"

Comment: **Records** can be filtered through `Where` Clause. **Groups** can be filtered through `Having` Clause

Comment: Which `RDBMS` you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just turn your where clause predicate into a subquery

```
select m.studentID, m.SSN, c.studentID, c.type,
    (Select count(*) from master
     Where SSN = m.SSN) ssnCount
from master m join class c on c.studentID = m.studentID 
where c.type = 'Honors"
    and (Select count(*) from master
         where SSN = m.SSN) > 1
```

Comment: No error messages, but this may be outputting all honors students.  How would I add a count column per SSN?

Comment: So I added  ssnCount (it's the same subquery in the Select clause)

Answer (score 1):

```
select master.SSN
from master
join class on master.studentID = class.student.ID
where class.type = 'Honors' 
group by master.SSN
having count(distinct master.studentID) > 1
```

Comment: Isn't he selecting four columns? Atleast three valid columns

Comment: Yes, but OP says he is worried about duplicate `studentID`s. If that query is not sufficient, it can be extended on request. But this is the most simple solution.

Comment: `select/group by master.SSN` i suppose: " to count studentID's for each SSN."

Comment: My original question was incorrectly worded.  I would like to count instances of StudentID's for each SSN.  I'm not concerned about duplicate StudentID's

Comment: @DJohnson1990: I updated the answer. Use `count(distinct master.studentID)`